# Hadoop YARN: Get a list of available queues

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way to get a list of all available YARN queues from the command line, without resorting to parsing the `capacity-scheduler.xml` file?

I'm using Hadoop version 2.7.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to use ResourceManager REST API, for example:

```
curl '<resourcemanager_host>:<http_port>/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler' | jq '.scheduler.schedulerInfo.queues.queue[] | .queueName’
```

will list all **top** level queues.

```
curl '<resourcemanager_host>:<http_port>/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler' | jq .
```

gives you all kind of information about scheduler/queues, thus using `jq` you can get any information out of it.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you browse to the <resourcemanager_host>:<http_port>/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler or similar such page, often the application queues are there and show the hierarchy along with current basic usage statistics.

Answer (score 30):

You can use the hadoop builtin `mapred` command-line tool

```
me@here.com$ mapred queue -list
======================
Queue Name : root.tenant1
Queue State : running
Scheduling Info : Capacity: 0.0, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
    ======================
    Queue Name : root.tenant1.default
    Queue State : running
    Scheduling Info : Capacity: 0.0, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
    ======================
    Queue Name : root.tenant1.users
    Queue State : running
    Scheduling Info : Capacity: 0.0, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
======================
Queue Name : root.tenant2
Queue State : running
Scheduling Info : Capacity: 0.0, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
    ======================
    Queue Name : root.tenant2.default
    Queue State : running
    Scheduling Info : Capacity: 0.0, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
    ======================
    Queue Name : root.tenant2.users
    Queue State : running
    Scheduling Info : Capacity: 0.0, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
======================
```

it provides a simple and nice output with hierarchy